# Running rspec for the first time but it show cannot load such file -- spec-helper(load error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

after i install rspec successfully ,but when i run rspec card_spec.rb in project/spec/models
it got error information like that:cannot load such file -- spec_helper(Loaderror).
anyone can help me to make my first rspec pass?

Comment: Did you run the rails generator to generate the `spec_helper` file? It will be `rails generate rspec:install`.

Comment: yes,i already did that and yes it success.

Answer (score 0):

No you should run your specs from your root directory. in `/path_to_your_app`, Try :

```
rspec ./spec/models/card_spec.rb
```

Comment: thx for your help.and i try this:rspec ./spec/models/card_spec.rb and it show setup:migrating and create_tables(:users) or create sequence.but it also wrong with relation "users" already exists.i want to know why it create tables although i have test database?

Comment: Have you setup your test database ? Does rake db:test:prepare returns any error ?

Comment: there is no error when i run rake db:test:prepare and i got a test database. what do i need to learn how to test my code? can u tell me the step?